# Add a vertex to the graph

Tags: java, graph

I want to read data from a file and construct a graph from it. I did everything, all vertices are created normally, but when I add them to the graph, their adjacent lists (which are maps, whose key value is adjacent vertex's number, and value is their distance) become empty. Can anyone, please, tell what's the problem with my code?

```
public class Vertex {
private int number;
private LinkedHashMap<Integer, Integer> adjacent;

public Vertex(int num) {
    this.number = num;
    this.adjacent = new LinkedHashMap<Integer, Integer>();
}
```

}

```
public class Graph {
private ArrayList<Vertex> vertices;
private int verticesSize = 201;

public Graph() {
    Vertex initialVertex = new Vertex(0);
    this.vertices = new ArrayList<Vertex>();
    for(int i = 0; i < verticesSize; i++) {
        vertices.add(i, initialVertex);
    }

}
```

}

```
public class Test {

public static void printGraph(Graph graph) {
    for(int i = 0; i < graph.getVerticesSize(); i++)
            System.out.println(graph.getVertices().get(i));
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    FileInputStream fStream = new FileInputStream("C:/Lusine/Programming/Java/dijkstraData.txt");
    // Use DataInputStream to read binary NOT text.
    BufferedReader bReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fStream));

    Graph graph = new Graph();
    String[] maps;

    String line;
    LinkedHashMap<Integer, Integer> currentMap = new LinkedHashMap<Integer, Integer>();

    while( (line = bReader.readLine()) != null) {
         maps = line.split("\t");
         int firstDigit = Integer.parseInt(maps[0]);

          Vertex v = new Vertex(firstDigit);

          for(int i = 1; i < maps.length; i++) {
             String[] vertexDistance = maps[i].split(",");
             int vertex = Integer.parseInt(vertexDistance[0]);
             int distance = Integer.parseInt(vertexDistance[1]);
             currentMap.put(vertex, distance);
          }

            v.setAdjacent(currentMap);
            graph.getVertices().set(firstDigit, v);
            System.out.println("\n" + firstDigit +"-th vertex is\n" + v);
            currentMap.clear();

    }
    printGraph(graph);
}
```

when I print v, it's ok, but when I print graph, all adjacent lists are empty. What's the problem?

Comment: but when you add them to the graph... What happens?  I think you forgot to finish describing the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Your loop boils down to

```
LinkedHashMap<Integer, Integer> currentMap = new LinkedHashMap<Integer, Integer>();

while ( ... ) {
     Vertex v = new Vertex(...);
     v.setAdjacent(currentMap);
     currentMap.clear();
}
```

So, you're storing the same map of adjacent vertices in every vertex, and you clear this map at the end of each iteration. So obviously, all the vertices share the same, empty map, at the end of the loop.

You should create a new LinkedHashMap at every iteration:

```
while ( ... ) {
    LinkedHashMap<Integer, Integer> currentMap = new LinkedHashMap<Integer, Integer>();
    Vertex v = new Vertex(...);
    v.setAdjacent(currentMap);
}
```

And you should not clear it, cince clearing it, well... clears it.